# How to include a lazy-loaded Component selector into another Component's HTML in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-template

I am trying to achieve lazy load in angular 2. 
 I have created lazy load by following [this link](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules). 
I have two components like home1 and home2. home1 has the top news section and home2 is for listing other news. 
 At first time only home1 will be displayed. 
After the user scrolls the page, home2 have to be loaded in home1.(like calling partial view in MVC).

I tried by calling home2 in home1 as `<app-home2-list></app-home2-list>`

but getting an error.

[image: Error]

I don't how to call home2 html in home1 html?.Is any other way available for implementing this?

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Const_Routing } from './app.routing';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Home2ListComponent } from './home2/home2-list/home2-list.component';
import { Home1ListComponent } from './home1/home1-list/home1-list.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    Home1ListComponent,
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Const_Routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home1-list.component.ts and home2-list.component.ts(both codes are same,api call is differ):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import '../../../assets/scripts/endlessriver.js';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { SharedService } from '../../Services/shared.service';
import { Home1Service } from './home1.service';
import { Home2ListComponent } from '../../home2/home2-list/home2-list.component';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home1-list',
  templateUrl: './home1-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home1-list.component.css','../../../assets/styles/common.css','../../../assets/styles/endlessriver.css'],
  providers: [Home1Service,SharedService]
})
export class Home1ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public Service: Home1Service,public CommonService:SharedService) { }

  @ViewChild('marqueeID') input: ElementRef;

  HomeList:any;
  HomeList1:any;
  HomeList2:any;
  HomeList3:any;
  sectionName:string;
  datetime:string;
  productId:number=2;
  getListingData(sectionName)
  {
              this.Service.getListingNews(sectionName,15).subscribe(
                  data => {
                      this.HomeList = data.map(e => {
                          return { SectionName:e.ChildName,ArticleId:e.ArticleId, HeadLine: e.HeadLine, Abstract: e.Abstract, ImageLink: e.ImageLink ,UpdatedDate:this.CommonService.getDateFormat(new Date(e.UpdatedDate),'others').toString()};
                      })
                  },
                  error => { console.log(error) });
                  this.Service.getListingNews("world",5).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.HomeList1 = data.map(e => {
                            return { Heading:'world',SectionName:e.ChildName,ArticleId:e.ArticleId, HeadLine: e.HeadLine, Abstract: e.Abstract, ImageLink: e.ImageLink ,UpdatedDate:this.CommonService.getDateFormat(new Date(e.UpdatedDate),'others').toString()};
                        })
                    },
                    error => { console.log(error) });
                    this.Service.getListingNews("national",5).subscribe(
                        data => {
                            this.HomeList2 = data.map(e => {
                                return {Heading:'national', SectionName:e.ChildName,ArticleId:e.ArticleId, HeadLine: e.HeadLine, Abstract: e.Abstract, ImageLink: e.ImageLink ,UpdatedDate:this.CommonService.getDateFormat(new Date(e.UpdatedDate),'others').toString()};
                            })
                        },
                        error => { console.log(error) });
                        this.Service.getListingNews("state",5).subscribe(
                            data => {
                                this.HomeList3 = data.map(e => {
                                    return { Heading:'state',SectionName:e.ChildName,ArticleId:e.ArticleId, HeadLine: e.HeadLine, Abstract: e.Abstract, ImageLink: e.ImageLink ,UpdatedDate:this.CommonService.getDateFormat(new Date(e.UpdatedDate),'others').toString()};
                                })
                            },
                            error => { console.log(error) });
  }
  getHomeList(name: string) 
  {
    if(name=="0")
    {
      return this.HomeList1;
    }
    else if(name=="1")
    {
      return this.HomeList2;
    }
    else
    {
      return this.HomeList3;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.datetime=this.CommonService.getDateFormat(new Date(),'home').toString();
    this.getListingData('TopNews');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    jQuery(this.input.nativeElement).endlessRiver({

    });
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.brkngBody').show();
    });
  }
}
```

home1.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Home1RoutingModule } from './home1-routing.module';
import { Home1ListComponent } from './home1-list/home1-list.component';
import { Home2ListComponent } from '../home2/home2-list/home2-list.component';
import { Home2RoutingModule } from '../home2/home2-routing.module';
import { Home2Module } from '../home2/home2.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home1RoutingModule,
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  declarations: [Home1ListComponent]
})
export class Home1Module { }
```

home2.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Home2RoutingModule } from './home2-routing.module';
import { Home2ListComponent } from './home2-list/home2-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home2RoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [Home2ListComponent]
})
export class Home2Module { }
```

home1-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Home1ListComponent } from './home1-list/home1-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [ {
  path: '',
  component: Home1ListComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Home1RoutingModule { }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txzead?embed=1&file=app/home1/home1.module.ts)**

Comment: Show your module, where you import the home1

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home1RoutingModule,
    Home2RoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [Home1ListComponent]
}) this is my home1.module.ts code

Comment: your home2 component module is not properly imported. import the same in app.module.ts or any module.ts file you have in your project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

//home2.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Home2RoutingModule } from './home2-routing.module';
import { Home2ListComponent } from './home2-list/home2-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home2RoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[Home2ListComponent],
  declarations: [Home2ListComponent]
})
export class Home2Module { }
```

//Home1.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Home1RoutingModule } from './home1-routing.module';
import { Home1ListComponent } from './home1-list/home1-list.component';
import { Home2ListComponent } from '../home2/home2-list/home2-list.component';
import { Home2RoutingModule } from '../home2/home2-routing.module';
import { Home2Module } from '../home2/home2.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home1RoutingModule,
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    Home1ListComponent
  ],
  declarations: [Home1ListComponent]
})
export class Home1Module { }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txzead?embed=1&file=app/home1/home1.module.ts)**

Comment: Register Home2List component in `home1.module.ts` and export the component as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Home1RoutingModule,
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    Home2ListComponent
  ],
  declarations: [Home1ListComponent]
}).... I tried this

Comment: but getting error "core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected directive 'Home2ListComponent' imported by the module 'Home1Module'. Please add a NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected directive 'Home2ListComponent' imported by the module 'Home1Module'. Please add a NgModule annotation."

Comment: @Girija : Check out the demo app

Comment: I tried to do the same in my code.but getting error.I added my code in https://angular-njbgxj.stackblitz.io/ url

Comment: check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmufzh?embed=1&file=app/home1/home1-list/home1-list.component.html

Comment: I don't know stackblitz.com.
Thanks for the info @santosh singh.

Answer (score 1):

If your Home2 component is in the different module then you'll have to add that to "exports" block.
Then only you'll be able to use that component in the Home1 module.

E.g.

Module 1

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [Home1Component],
      exports: [Home1Component]
    })
    export class Module1 { }
```

Module 2

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';    
@NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [Home2Component],
      exports: [Home2Component]
    })
    export class Module2 { }
```

AppModule

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        Module1,
        Module2
      ],
      declarations: [],
      exports: []
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I added both components in imports section of AppModule. but the issue is not solved

Comment: Okay, can you please check the selector of both the components?

Comment: Components should be added to declarations section, not in the imports sections.

Comment: i added component in declarations section and getting this error  "Type Home1ListComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and Home1Module! Please consider moving Home1ListComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and Home1Module. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes Home1ListComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and Home1Module."

Comment: But if you're importing the modules then you don't need to declare the components from the module that you've already imported.
Can you please add the Fiddle for the same?

Comment: And when you're using the loadChildren, then you don't have to import the modules. It'll be loaded automatically when the route matches.

Answer (score 0):

When you visualize this error, you need to add your component class name to the “imports” structure of the @NgModule of the AppModule.

For example if you component class **home1** declare the selector **app-home2-list**.

**app/home2.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home2-list',
  templateUrl: 'app/home2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/mycomponent.css']
})
export class Home2{ // Component code here}
```

**app/home1.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// Add the reference to the component so you can use the seletor
// inside the template 'app.component.html'
import { Home2} from './home2.component';

if(!/localhost/.test(document.location.host))
{
    enableProdMode();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home1',
  templateUrl: 'app/home1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/home1.component.css']
})

export class Home1Component{ // App component code here}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyComponentModule
  ],
  declarations: [Home1Component],
  bootstrap: [Home1Component, Home2Component]})

export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```